# Allowing Tensorflow to Use both GPU and Physical System Memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

For a project I'm working on, I am using an altered version of Mask RCNN to train a model that will find objects in an image. These images are relatively small, about 300 x 200 pixels, and I train them for a relatively long time, around 100 epochs.

However, my main question relates to the batch size and how Tensorflow allocates memory on the gpu for the validation stage per epoch. I want to increase my batch size to help better smooth out the validation curve, as well as increase the accuracy of the overall model. However, if I increase my batch size to drastically, I get a `OOM: GPU out-of-momory` and `keras_scratch_graph` error. I'm currently working with two NVIDIA Quadro P5000s that have 16GB of vram each. having about 3 images per GPU, I can have a max batch size of 6 before it errors out. I've looked around and most people either say to just decrease the batch size, which I would prefer not to do, or enable GPU growth, which I couldn't get to work either. I could decrease the complexity of my model to decrease the size of tensors that are being evaluated, but I don't want to risk it as it could cause my accuracy to decrease, or loss to increase.

Is there a way that I can offset some images onto my physical systems memory, or am I purely limited to the amount of ram I have available on my GPU? Are their any more compact or robust methods out there that could solve this issue?

Comment: [https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-large-model-support](https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-large-model-support)

Comment: [https://github.com/cybertronai/gradient-checkpointing](https://github.com/cybertronai/gradient-checkpointing)

Comment: Also, you can simulate big batch in exchange of time via `gradient accumulation`, keras package: https://pypi.org/project/keras-gradient-accumulation/

Comment: Or, if this is only for validation at the end of epoch, then compute validation on CPU (`with tf.device('cpu')`)

Comment: Thanks @Slowpoke, I'll look into these repos and functions and see if it can solve my issue :).

Comment: Start with gradient accumulation. It is the simplest and should give you big batch size you want